# Moving tiles BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I have been working on a puzzle and for some reason this does not work.

each slide is a random letter, "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o" I know that 50% of the time this can be a unsolvable puzzle (don't know how to avoid it except for having constants)

Besides it being unsolvable half the time the movements don't work, could it be because the tiles are letters and not numbers? The movements are controlled by the wasd keys (w=up, a=left, s=down, d=right)

The final thing is can this be any more simple/effective?

```
echo  ____ ____ ____ ____
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide1% ^| %slide2% ^| %slide3% ^| %slide4% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide5% ^| %slide6% ^| %slide7% ^| %slide8% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide9% ^| %slide10% ^| %slide11% ^| %slide12% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide13% ^| %slide14% ^| %slide15% ^| %slide16%  ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|

choice /c wasdr /n
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto movew
if %errorlevel% == 2 goto movea
if %errorlevel% == 3 goto moves
if %errorlevel% == 4 goto moved
if %errorlevel% == 5 goto reset
:movew
if %pos% GEQ 13 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% + 4
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% + 4
:movea
if %pos% == 4 goto display
if %pos% == 8 goto display
if %pos% == 12 goto display
if %pos% == 16 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% + 1
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% + 1
goto display
:moves
if %pos% LEQ 4 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% - 4
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% - 4
goto display
:moved
if %pos% == 1 goto display
if %pos% == 5 goto display
if %pos% == 9 goto display
if %pos% == 13 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% - 1
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% - 1
goto display
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered that the only tiles that can move are those directly above, below and to either side of the empty square?These four tiles have names (letters) and therefore instead of moving wens, you could say move akeh. A move is then a matter of switching Rx and Rspace...

Comment: Choose the letters to be presented as `choice` by looking from Rspace +/-1 and +/-4 - after checking (left Rs %% 4 neq 1, right Rs %% 4 neq 0, up Rs-4 gtr 0 down Rs+4 lss 17), pick up the letters, put them in a variable, add `q` to quit for luck & use `choice /c %varname% /n`. You understand `delayedexpansion` so `!varname:~%errorlevel,1%!` is the letter moving (well, you'd have to add a character to the start of `varname`).

Comment: Your original design used numbers in squares Rx (x=1..16). Now you're using letters. If Rs is the space then if s=1, you can only move Right or Down. s=2,3,Left;Right;Down s=4,L;D s=5,R;U;D etc. so `if s mod 4 not =1` (coded as `if S %% 4 neq 1`) you can move R, etc. For any S therefore, the tiles that may be chosen to move are S-1,S+1,S-4 and S+4 for L,R,U,D provided they pass the tests (like `if S %% 4 neq 1` which excludes S-1 (Left) if the test fails). So, pick up the (2-4) letters from the tiles which *can* move into the space, add `q` to quit...

Comment: You would possibly want to write a subroutine to switch the space with a neighbouring tile, so if R5 has the space and R4 contains `K` then the user selects `k`, K is in R4 so switch R4 and R5. You could use this routine to randomise your start position and be assured it can be solved. Initialise R1=A..R15=O, R16=S then execute a routine to figure out which are the tiles surrounding S (15 and 12);randomly choose one and switch that tile with the space. Repeat these steps say 10000+random(5000) times. You now have a random start position that MUST be solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *right* answer to your question is: "Yes!".

However, in this case your next question would be "How?" for sure, and the only way to answer this new question is showing code. So here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "size=4"
set "empty=  "

:label-5 reset
rem Populate the puzzle with random numbers
set /A size2=size*size-1
set "numbers="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%size2%) do (
   set "number= %%i"
   set "numbers=!numbers!!number:~-2!"
)
set "numbers=%numbers%%empty%"
set "nums=%numbers%"
set /A n=size2+1
for /L %%j in (1,1,%size%) do (
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%size%) do (
      set /A num=!random!%%n*2, numP2=num+2, n-=1
      for /F "tokens=1,2" %%m in ("!num! !numP2!") do (
         set "slide[%%j][%%i]=!nums:~%%m,2!"
         if "!nums:~%%m,2!" equ "%empty%" set /A i=%%i, j=%%j
         set "nums=!nums:~0,%%m!!nums:~%%n!"
      )
   )
)

:refresh
rem Show the puzzle
set "nums="
< NUL (
   cls
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%size%) do set /P "=.____"
   echo .
   for /L %%j in (1,1,%size%) do (
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%size%) do set /P "=|    "
      echo ^|
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%size%) do set /P "=| !slide[%%j][%%i]! " & set "nums=!nums!!slide[%%j][%%i]!"
      echo ^|
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%size%) do set /P "=|____"
      echo ^|
   )
)
if "%nums%" equ "%numbers%" goto completed

:getKey
rem Move the empty square
choice /C wasdrx /N
if errorlevel 5 goto label-%errorlevel%  Reset or eXit
set /A "mod2=%errorlevel% %% 2, newJ=j+(%errorlevel%-2)*mod2, newI=i+(%errorlevel%-3)*^!mod2"
if not defined slide[%newJ%][%newI%] goto getKey
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("%newI% %newJ%") do set "slide[%j%][%i%]=!slide[%%j][%%i]!" & set "slide[%%j][%%i]=%empty%"
set /A i=newI, j=newJ
goto refresh

:completed
echo Completed^^^!

:label-6 exit
```